while making a change in a price ecommerce app by selecting the different size i get error in unsupported operand type
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Internal Server Error: /product/t-shirts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 332, in check_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view products.views.get_product didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[20/Jul/2024 12:48:11] "GET /product/t-shirts/?size=XL HTTP/1.1" 500 68697

this is my products.models page
from django.db import models

from base.models import BaseModel

from django.utils.text import slugify


class Category(BaseModel):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="categories")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)

        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.category_name


class ColorVariant(BaseModel):
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.color_name


class SizeVariant(BaseModel):
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.size_name


class Product(BaseModel):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    categorys = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="products",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
    )
    price = models.IntegerField()

    products_description = models.TextField()

    color_variant = models.ManyToManyField(ColorVariant, blank=True)

    size_variant = models.ManyToManyField(SizeVariant, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.product_name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.product_nam

    def get_product_price_by_size(self, size):
        return self.price + str(SizeVariant.objects.get(size_name=size).price)


class ProductImage(BaseModel):
    products = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_images"
    )

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product")


the error message clearly states the problem comes from your views. show us this code

your function get_product_price_by_size may be the problem, but i can't be sure without the proper view. price should be an int from your own model, but you convert it to str

Show your views

In product modal try updating the class method -
This -
def get_product_price_by_size(self, size):
    return self.price + str(SizeVariant.objects.get(size_name=size).price)

to this -
def get_product_price_by_size(self, size):
    return str(self.price) + str(SizeVariant.objects.get(size_name=size).price)

